# Retrieve Parents Recursively Without CTEs

Tags: mysql, laravel, recursive-query, mysql-5.7

I have a table `tasks` that looks something like the below. There's an ID and parent_id column. I need to run two separate queries, the first of which will return me all of the children recursively. The second which will return me all of the parents recursively. I'm currently using MySQL 5.7 (plans to move but too big a task for all client dbs at present).

**Table Data**

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23850 | Task #1 |  |
| 23851 | Task #2 | 23850 |
| 23852 | Task #3 | 23851 |
| 23853 | Task #4 | 23852 |
| 23854 | Task #5 | 23853 |
| 23855 | Task #6 | 23854 |
| 23856 | Task #7 | 23855 |
| 23857 | Task #8 | 23856 |
| 23858 | Task #9 | 23857 |
| 23859 | Task #10 | 23858 |

I have this query below that will return me all of the children recursively, it works perfectly and is fairly quick on a database with millions of records. Although could be quicker. My dilemma is with returning parents. Is this even possible without using recursive CTEs dynamically? I can most probably union and join in the tables but i guess that would require knowledge of how many parents there are.

```sql
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id
from    (select * from tasks
         order by parent_id, id) tasks_sorted,
        (select @pv := '23855') initialisation
where   (find_in_set(id, @pv) > 0 OR find_in_set(parent_id, @pv))
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id);
```

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23855 | Task #6 | 23854 |
| 23856 | Task #7 | 23855 |
| 23857 | Task #8 | 23856 |
| 23858 | Task #9 | 23857 |
| 23859 | Task #10 | 23858 |

Any advice here is appreciated.

For reference the app is built in Laravel, and there's a requirement in the SPA being consumed by this Laravel API to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that you hat was very good, but to get the parent you need to reverse the order and compare the id to the concatinated parent_id

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id
from    (select * from tasks
         order by parent_id DESC LIMIT 10000) tasks_sorted,
        (select @pv := '23855') initialisation
where   (find_in_set(id, @pv) > 0 OR find_in_set(parent_id, @pv))
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', parent_id)
ORDER BY id
```

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23850 | Task | #1 |
| 23851 | Task #2 | 23850 |
| 23852 | Task #3 | 23851 |
| 23853 | Task #4 | 23852 |
| 23854 | Task #5 | 23853 |
| 23855 | Task #6 | 23854 |
| 23856 | Task #7 | 23855 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5NOD9adn)